# How to stop ASP.NET from changing IDs in order to perform some operation

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am creating dynamic radio button lists

```
Dim rdbQuestion As New RadioButtonList
```

and there dynamic Ids as

```
rdbQuestion.ID = "Question_" & row("Id").ToString
```

And when the page rendered the id of Radio Button Lists changes to something like this

```
AssessmentPerforma_Question_1, AssessmentPerforma_Question_2, AssessmentPerforma_Question_3..... AssessmentPerforma_Question_n
```

How can I stop asp.net from changing IDs in order to perform a operation like this

```
Sub btnSave_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("Question_1"), RadioButtonList)
        Response.Write(rbl.SelectedValue)
End Sub
```

Comment: `c#` tag seems pointless.

Comment: You don't need to - `FindControl` uses the server-side ID, not the ClientId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line....

```
rbdQuestion.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static
```

Comment: thank you for your help..but i am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: add this line after creating the object of rbdQuestion.

Comment: Response.Write(rbl.SelectedValue)

Comment: you are providing the invalid control id on this line 'Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("Question_1"), RadioButtonList)' that causes the null to the rbl variable...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34510/discussion-between-adward-and-abdul-basit)